# Grails .xls file download

Tags: grails

I want a link on my view page and it should extend with .xls file.  When I click on that link then I should able to see the file downloaded.  That file should be only in .xls.  How do I do this?

Comment: why groovy on grails! You can't say, you can check http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1213 for more detail.

Comment: Please be more clear in what you are after. Do you want to use a GSP to generate an .xls file?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [g:link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html) that points to a controller action then writes the .xls data to the response.  It would look something like this...

view.gsp

```
<g:link controller="foo" action="download" >Download</g:link>
```

then you'll need a controller action...

```
class FooController{

    def download = {
        def file = new File("/path/to/file/somefile.xls"); //<-- you'll probably want to pass in the file name dynamically with the 'params' map    
        response.setContentType("application/excel")
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${file.getName()}")

        response.outputStream << file.newInputStream()

    }

}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: :It is working perfectly bt i also need to know that where my file has been downloaded.

Comment: It's specific to the browser, user and operating system.  You won't know where the file is downloaded on the client side.

Comment: I simply want to know that when I click on the link then the file which is on server i.e "/home/anuj/Del11_Final4/del11-his/del11-his/contributions/pharmacy-app/web-app" should be downloaded to my local machine whatever location I want to save it.

Thanx in advance @Michael

Comment: @AB You don't have any control as to where the user chooses to save the file. As Michael says it is up to the user, their browser, and the operating system. As well as that there is no way to know where a user actually saved the file on their computer. This is true of all web sites and web apps, not just Grails.