# Dynamic download link

Tags: grails

Code of view page for link

```
<a style="margin-left:70px;" href="${grailsApplication.config.grails.project.dir}/download?path=web-app/${What should i write here?}">Sample_Upload_Format.xls</a>
```

I have a drop-down in my view page which consist of 4 fields and below that i link is there.When I select one of the field and click the link then the .xls file linked with that link den it should upload that respective .xls file attached with it.

e.g i have four fields in dropdown

1-Product_Type
2-Product_Name
3-Generic_Name
4-Manufacturer

And one link lies below it

Sample_Product_File.xls

and 4 files are there in my File System naming with 
1-Product_Type.xls
2-Product_Name.xls
3-Generic_Name.xls
4-Manufacturer.xls

When i select Product_name and click on the link Sample_Product_File.xls then Product_name.xls should be downloaded.

Comment: @AB __*Please*__ stop just calling your questions "Groovy on Grails".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails .xls file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594819/grails-xls-file-download)

Comment: Did you implement `DownloadController` already?

Comment: Code of view page for link
<a style="margin-left:70px;" href="${grailsApplication.config.grails.project.dir}/download?path=web-app/${What should i write here?}">Sample_Upload_Format.xls</a>

Comment: @tim_yates: i'm sorry bt i'm very new to this technology.I'm fresher n working on this technolgy.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov: Earlier what i tried

Comment: @AB Yeah, but that doesn't stop you thinking of a title other than an [incorrect name for the technology you are using](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1213)...

Comment: @IgorArtamonov: Till now i didn't use the controller.I have given a path in my create.gsp page which extends a sample_file name.
<a style="margin-left:70px;" href="${grailsApplication.config.grails.project.dir}/Sample_File_Upload">Sample_Upload_Format.xls</a>
where grailsApplication.config.grails.project.dir = "http://localhost:8080/pharmacy-app/"

Comment: Ok, start with implementing controller. W/o controoler it's don't matter what link you have